# Não consigo logar em chat

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, chat, login

Eu até já sei que é algo específico comigo, mas não sei como resolver.

Não consigo entrar no chat a não ser anonimamente. Por consequência o chat dos moderadores que é fechado dá 404 pra mim.

Estou logado na rede, mas no chat não e não adianta logar que ele continua *deslogado*, mesmo aceitando o login.

Estou usando FF (desktop), mas testei em outros navegadores (incluindo um que nunca havia entrado antes) e até aba privada. Já *desloguei* geral na rede e tentei de novo, fico logado nos *sites*, mas no chat nunca fica logado. Sem uso de *proxy* ou qualquer coisa diferente.

Não limparei todos os *cookies. Já apaguei todos os *cookies* `*.stackexchange.com` e `*.stackoverflow.com`, bem como sessões e *storage* e o que for desses domínios que estejam no *browser*. Nada resolveu.

Já me falaram que não estou banido :P

Precisam de mais informações?

Comment: Uma coisa que pode ajudar é limpar o `local storage` e `session storage` do navegador, mas acredito que já tentou =P https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWFQC.png

Comment: @MarceloBoni agora sim, nada.

Comment: Uma pergunta ingenua, usou em um provedor de internet diferente, tipo 4G conectado ao seu PC (compartilhado)? Por mais que improvável, tem algum proxy? ... Isto pode ser de fator for um bug, notei o rray ao 12:00 mais ou menos no chat, mas depois não o notei mais, seria interessante algum moderador confirmar, se confirmado ai seria o "Metão" para agilizar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Usei só um provedor, sem proxy, tudo dentro do normal de sempre.

Comment: Cá para mim você foi banido :)

Comment: @ramaral pensei nisso. Porém se você é banido e nem fica sabendo, nada informa que é isso, é ridículo, é o cúmulo da UX errada e que deve estar há anos rolando, por isso não posso acreditar em tamanha incompetência. Sem falar que para moderador deveria ter um tratamento diferente e um CM ser informado imediatamente e tomar alguma providência, porque não é algo comum e é que cria dificuldades para o trabalho de moderação. E se foi o caso, queria entender como aconteceu, não consigo imaginar um motivo. Estou há mais de 24hs assim.

Comment: Eu estava brincando. Não acredito que alguém possa ser banido sem que lhe seja dado conhecimento.

Comment: @ramaral não tenho tanta certeza :D Curioso que esta semana respondi uma pesquisa, hoje as respostas seriam diferentes.

Comment: @Maniero isso já aconteceu comigo. Demorou um bocado, mas voltou ao normal.

Comment: Fazes login normalmente, e parece que deu, mas depois nada, né? E se tentares login outra vez... sempre o mesmo em loop, @Maniero?

Comment: @JNat exatamente isso.

Comment: Experimentei fazer refresh no teu perfil de chat, @Maniero: nada ainda?

Comment: @JNat nada, mesma coisa, no SP continua 404 e no EP só vejo como anônimo, depois de ter feito o login normalmente

Comment: Ok, vou pedir a um dev para dar uma olhadela ;)

Answer (score 2):

A primeira coisa a fazer é garantir que você não está bloqueando cookies de terceiros ou usando complementos que bloqueiem scripts de terceiros no Stack Overflow ou no Stack Exchange.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando isso for verificado, efetue logout e login novamente em meta.stackexchange.com primeiro e depois visite o chat.

De acordo com nossos registros, você ainda não tentou efetuar logout / login.

Comment: Sim, isso é o normal, inclusive por isso que nunca tive problemas. Eu fiz login várias vezes nos últimos 3 dias e passam todos, e só não dá acesso aos chats. A única diferença desta tela pra minha é que eu estou ocupando mais espaço em disco que a sua :P Nada mudou esses dias, nem atualização do *browser* ocorreu. E como eu mostrei na pergunta tentei outros browsers. Até outra máquina tentei.

Comment: Podes experimentar fazer logout do meta.stackexchange.com, e login aí outra vez, e _depois_ tentar aceder ao chat outra vez, @Maniero? Ou já tentaste isso?

Comment: @JNat Eu tinha feito e nenhum resultado, feito agora deu certo.